# How to get path file installer on custom action

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have problem about create setup file . I have project winform, after build solution I have 2 files setup.exe and SetupXinvitroAC.msi contained in folder:

> E:\Data\Progamming\DotNET\Xinvitro\Code\SetupXinvitroAC\Debug. Then I copy file Drivers.exe to same folder.

I goto the custom actions viewer, and select the properties for your custom action. then enter the following as the CustomActionData parameter:

> /TARGETDIR="[TARGETDIR]\"

in project I add Intaller file. I overwirite method OnBeforeInstall

```
protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
      base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
      if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\Windows\twain_32\Scanner\AVA6PlusG\AVA6PlusG.ds"))
     {
       string path = Context.Parameters["TARGETDIR"];
       TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\text.txt");
       tw.WriteLine(path);
       tw.Close();
       Process.Start( path + "Drivers.exe");     
       //I expect it will is Process.Start(   "E:\Data\Progamming\DotNET\Xinvitro\Code\SetupXinvitroAC\Debug\Drivers.exe");           
     }
}
```

But after installed, I open text.txt file it printed 'C:\Program Files (x86)\catvangsolution\Xinvitro\' not like I wanted, this is folder I install to.

I want ask how I get path like `"E:\Data\Progamming\DotNET\Xinvitro\Code\SetupXinvitroAC\Debug"` to run file Drivers.exe. Thanks.

Comment: Just to expand on the answer by Igor, referring to TARGETDIR is completely the wrong folder - that's where the files will be installed TO, the main application folder! You're asking where the MSI setup is running FROM, and that's the SourceDir property.

Answer (score 2):

To receive path from where you launch installer use:
 - MSI - [SourceDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857(v=vs.85).aspx) property
 - EXE (InstallShield) - [SETUPEXEDIR](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/SETUPEXEDIR.htm) property.

I guess, SourceDir will also work for bootstrapped EXEs (with help of WiX).